# Reading input as array

Tags: java

I'm just trying to read the input integers from the user for example

> 2 2 1 1 1  < as a whole

In the debugger, it works places each integer but when

the resulting array is printed something like `[I@19eda2c` is printed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int count=0;
int[] array = new int[10];
String input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter up to 10 integers: ");
while(scan.hasNextInt()){

array[count] = scan.nextInt();
count++;

}
System.out.println(array);

   }

}
```

I understand now that it needs to be printed with a `for` loop or `toString` method

but I realized when I run the code,

the program waits for me even though the user inputs the integers

is my scanner logistics incorrect?

Comment: The value being printed is the memory address of the array

Comment: You can't print the elements of the array just by System.out.println(array);. Iterate through the array and print each element in the array.

Comment: `toString()` method is called implicitly on the `array` object, which is not implemented to print array's content. It just prints the memory address. Use `toString()` method of `Arrays` class instead.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `java.util.Arrays.toString()` method for a 1D array .

or

`java.util.Arrays.deepToString()` for multi-dimensional arrays.

Your program is fine *except that it will read 12 integers if user enters 12 numbers. Your loop needs to run from 0 to 9 to read 10 numbers and not as long as there are tokens in the input*

Here is how `Arrays.toString()` works:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's
>   elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are
>   separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).
>   Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(int)

Here is how `Arrays.deepToString()` works:

> Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the
>   specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the
>   string representation contains their contents and so on. This method
>   is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings.

For more, read the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(array); // prints value from default toString() method                 
                           // implementation (e.g. 'className + '@' + hashCode' in Java Oracle)
```

You should use something like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

to print values.

Better is to use `List` instead of `array`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   String input;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   while(scan.hasNextInt())
   {
      array.add(scan.nextInt());
   }
   System.out.println("Count=" + array.size());
   System.out.println(array);       
}
```

Comment: it does not print reference it prints `System.out.println(array.toString())` i.e. textual representation of object when you will see toString method in `Object` class return values of `toString` method is `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Answer (score 1):

You can't print the elements of the array just by `System.out.println(array);`. Iterate through the array and print each element in the array.

```
for(int index=0; index < count; index++ )
   System.out.println(array[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just printing textual representation of `array` object, use for loop to iterate in array and to display its content.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int[] array = new int[10];
        String input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter up to 10 integers: ");
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {

            array[count] = scan.nextInt();
            count++;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);   
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its not  hashcode. Textual representation of object. +1though.

Comment: yup, thanks for correcting, System.out.println(array) is same as System.out.println(array.toString())